# Assign a different prop value on every iteration within a .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have created a table which ultimately returns 5 rows and 5 columns.

For each cell I want to have a random number of cells in a different colour when the page loads, however at the moment all the cells remain the same colour.

I want the prop `isLit` to be `true` or `false` on each iteration for each cell, this will determine if the cell is a different colour or not.

Any advice on how to do this?

```
static defaultProps = {
  nrows: 5,
  ncols: 5,
  chanceLightStartsOn: 0.25,
};

// [...]

render() {
  const isLit = this.props.chanceLightStartsOn > Math.random();

  const mainBoard = Array.from({ length: this.props.nrows }).map(() => (
    <tr>
      {Array.from({ length: this.props.ncols }).map((x, index) => (
        <Cell isLit={isLit} />
      ))}
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table className="Board">
      <tbody>
        <h1>BOARD</h1>
        {mainBoard}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Cell.js

```
class Cell extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(evt) {
    // call up to the board to flip cells around this cell
    this.props.flipCellsAroundMe();
  }

  render() {
    let classes = "Cell" + (this.props.isLit ? " Cell-lit" : "");

    return <td className={classes} onClick={this.handleClick} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `<Cell isLit={!!Math.round(Math.random())} /> `

Comment: @Titus is right! Important is that you compute the `Math.random` inside the loop. Otherwise the result of `Math.random` will be the same for all cells

Comment: thank you for your quick response. I should have asked way sooner.... gah!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are evaluating `this.props.chanceLightStartsOn > Math.random()` only once and passing same value of `isLit` to all the `Cell` components.

What you should be doing is checking if `this.props.chanceLightStartsOn` is greater than `Math.random()` inside the `.map()` function so that random number is generated in each iteration.

Change

```
<Cell isLit={isLit} />
```

to

```
<Cell isLit={this.props.chanceLightStartsOn > Math.random()} />
```

Comment: thank you so much @Yousaf this worked and great explanation